# What happens when a company stops trading? (pink sheets)

Tags: stocks, investing, pink-sheets, market-capitalization

I've inherited many shares in a company traded on the pink sheets.  Its market cap is lower than its assets. Many assets of its assets are quite boring (bonds).  It does not carry debt. Because no information has come out from the company for quite a while the price of the company continues to decline. Although, one can get a copy of their annual audit, by asking.

I have so many questions: here's a few.

What will happen if the stock price just continues to decline? 
What would happen if folks just stop trading it? 
What if the company goes private? How do they decide the fair value of the outstanding stocks?

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if the stock price just continues to decline?

Nothing.

> What would happen if folks just stop trading it?

Nothing.

> What if the company goes private?

Then they will have to buy you out based on some agreed upon price, as voted by the board and (potentially) approved by the shareholders. Depending on the corporation charter, the board may not be required to seek the shareholders' approval, but if the price the board agreed upon is unreasonable you can sue and prevent the transaction.

> How do they decide the fair value of the outstanding stocks?

Through a process called "[valuation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/valuation.asp)", there are accounting firms which specialize in this area of public accounting.